# How do I find last year's WTD(week to date) data in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

SO here's I have found TYWTD(this year week to date)
I got the query for this year but I need to know how to write a query for last year 4-5-4 calendar date.

If I pull reports today, then the date range should be following.

this year WTD date range should be 6/11/17 - 6/13/17
last year WTD date range should be 6/12/17 - 6/14/17

Can anyone advise me for last year WTD?

Thank you!

```
                        SELECT MAX(te.StoreID) AS StoreID, 
                               SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity) AS Sales, 
                               SUM(te.Cost * te.Quantity) AS Cost,  
                               COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionNumber) AS Trxn,
                               SUM(te.Quantity) AS Quantity 
                        FROM   TransactionEntry te 
                               INNER JOIN [Transaction] t 
                                       ON te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber 
                                          AND te.StoreID = t.StoreID 
                               LEFT JOIN item i 
                                      ON te.itemID = i.ID 
                               LEFT JOIN Department d 
                                      ON i.DepartmentID = d.ID 
                        WHERE  d.ID <> 8 
                               AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
                               AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) <= dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
                        GROUP  BY te.StoreID) AS TYWTD
```

Comment: Adding a [date/calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) to your database is a great way to simplify queries like this.

Comment: Don't you mean `Last year WTD date range should be 6/12/16 - 6/14/16`?

Comment: oops! yes you are right! LYWTD should be 6/12/16 - 6/14/16!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting a year from `GetDate()` should do the trick.

```
dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())), convert(date, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())))
```

This yields `2016-06-12`.

Here is the updated script.
**Updated again.**

```
SELECT MAX(te.StoreID) AS StoreID, 
                               SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity) AS Sales, 
                               SUM(te.Cost * te.Quantity) AS Cost,  
                               COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionNumber) AS Trxn,
                               SUM(te.Quantity) AS Quantity 
                        FROM   TransactionEntry te 
                               INNER JOIN [Transaction] t 
                                       ON te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber 
                                          AND te.StoreID = t.StoreID 
                               LEFT JOIN item i 
                                      ON te.itemID = i.ID 
                               LEFT JOIN Department d 
                                      ON i.DepartmentID = d.ID 
                        WHERE  d.ID <> 8 
                               AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())), convert(date, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())))
                               AND dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())), convert(date, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())))
                        GROUP  BY te.StoreID) AS TYWTD
```

Comment: data verified and it works!!!! I did update the second part and it works!!! Thank you again!!!!